# Assign an animation to all unordered list except a specific ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the code below to allow me to fadein a div when I begin to scroll, which is assign to all of my unordered list. Is there a way I can tell the script to not assign this function to a specific ul

**Example**

I want all UL to fade in but would like ul class"test" to not fade, but to just be static.

```
 tiles = $("ul li").fadeTo(0, 0);
  $(window).scroll(function(d,h) {
  tiles.each(function(i) {
    a = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
    b = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    if (a < b) $(this).fadeTo(500,1);
 });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `:not()` selector

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bmcqsaf5/)

```
tiles = $("ul li:not(.test)").fadeTo(0, 0);
  $(window).scroll(function(d,h) {
  tiles.each(function(i) {
    a = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
    b = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    if (a < b) $(this).fadeTo(500,1);
 });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove items with the `.test` class from the collection using [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/).

```
tiles = $("ul li").not("ul.test li").fadeTo(0, 0);
```